# ShareCompat set the recipient programmatically in Google+

Tags: android, android-intent, share

I wood like set recipient from my circle in Google+. How can I do this?

```
Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(activity)
            .setText(text)
            .setType("text/plain")
            .getIntent();

activity.startActivity(shareIntent);
```

Now, when call this function, I can share with "My circles", and I should by hand choose my friend from circles. Is there any way to do this programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

The point behind `ShareCompat` is to let the *user* choose where the *user* wants to share the content, which may or may not have anything to do with "circles".

If you instead wish to tie your sharing to some specific service that has "circles", go find some API for that specific service, and see what they offer.

Comment: Sorry, forgot specify, I need share with my friend in Google+

Comment: @user3273765: You will need to see if Google+ has some specific API that allows you to share with a particular friend/circle/octagon/whatever.